# Refer to cell by contents of nearby cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sheet where I want to use a formula to refer to a field on another sheet. I do not know the exact cell address, but I know it's the cell right next to the cell where it says "Niels Brinch".

How do I reference the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which columns both "Niels Brinch" and the cell you're looking for are in, then you can achieve this with a VLOOKUP.

Your formula would include something like

```
=VLOOKUP("Niels Brinch", A1:B20, 2, false)
```

In this case I'm assuming the name appears in column A and the cell you're looking for is in column B and that you only have 20 rows of data.  If that isn't the case, you'd need to adjust the second parts of the function.  Replace the range with a table containing what you're looking for.  The column with the name should be the first column in this range for the lookup to work.

Comment: And then I refer to the other sheet before A1?

Comment: Yes. Sorry the range would be 'Sheet1!A1:B20' or whatever the appropriate range and sheet name would be.